# StackExchange.Redis - how to clone hash map

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Is any StackExchange.Redis api to clone hash map or better to go with redis lua script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to clone/copy any Redis data type is with the [`DUMP`](https://redis.io/commands/dump) and [`RESTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/restore) commands combo. It is also the fastest in most cases.

To avoid sending the payload back and forth, a Lua script definitely the best way for that (https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/d30b3c40a72a07f23c70):

```
-- @desc:   The fastest, type-agnostic way to copy a Redis key
-- @usage:  redis-cli --eval copy_key.lua <source> <dest> , [NX]

local s = KEYS[1]
local d = KEYS[2]

if redis.call("EXISTS", d) == 1 then
  if type(ARGV[1]) == "string" and ARGV[1]:upper() == "NX" then
    return nil
  else
    redis.call("DEL", d)
  end
end

redis.call("RESTORE", d, 0, redis.call("DUMP", s))
return "OK"
```